# creating a global variable dynamically in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to create a global variable in ROBOT framework. I will executing n number of scripts,

In the first script, I will be checking a condition, based on that I want to create a variable, which will be used by remaining scripts.

__init__.robot (here I want to set the variable)  first.robot second.robot

Please let me know if this is possible in ROBOT.

Thanks
Anil

Comment: How do I ask a good question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

The built-in library of keywords contains the keyword [Set Global Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable). From the documentation:

> Makes a variable available globally in all tests and suites.
>
> Variables set with this keyword are globally available in all test
>   cases and suites executed after setting them. Setting variables with
>   this keyword thus has the same effect as creating from the command
>   line using the options --variable or --variablefile. Because this
>   keyword can change variables everywhere, it should be used with care.

Example:

```
Set global variable    ${the variable name}    this is the value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Environment Variables` which are global by default. It's avaliable in the `Operating System` library. They are limited to `String` variables, and having the following syntax:

`Set Environment Variable  %{ENV_VAR_NAME}`